# Not displaying input tag on certain devices

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to not display different input tags for different devices.

I have three input tags `<input class="desktop"/> <input class='tablet'><input class= 'mobile'>`

I'm not displaying desktop and mobile input tags by adding the css like this:

```css
.desktop {
 @media(max-width: 767px){
    display: none
 }}

.mobile {
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
    display: none;
 }}
```

I'm having difficulty restricting it for tablet though. My tablet dimensions are between 768px and 1024 px

I've tried doing this but it doesn't work:

```css
@media (max-width:768px) and (min-width:1024px) {
    display: none;
}
```

Any ideas on how I can control the input tag to only show between these dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a syntax error. You need to put the class selector inside the media query like this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

See [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) on w3schools

**edited** The media query just has the max-width and min-width the wrong way round. See below

```css
/* apply at widths below 768px */
@media (max-width:768px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightskyblue;
  }
  .tablet, .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* apply from widths between 768px and 1024px */
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1024px) {
  body {
    background-color: goldenrod;
  }
  .mobile, .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* apply from widths above 1024px */
@media (min-width:1024px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightseagreen;
  }
  .mobile, .tablet {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<input class='mobile' placeholder="mobile">
<input class='tablet' placeholder="tablet">
<input class='desktop' placeholder="desktop">
```

Comment: Hi Adam, It's not a syntax error since the way I've written it works for desktop and mobile. What I'm having difficulty is restricting the input tag  for tablet to only display b/w 768px and 1024px

Comment: Added an example. Hope this helps

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry for the bum steer in my first reply. Have a great weekend!